# Stop Postfix/Qmail from using local handler in CentOS/PLESK

Tags: postfix

Addresses with the same domain as my vhost are causing Postfix and QMail to revert to a local network instead of just outright sending the mail.  I thought I had this problem fixed with the [Luke Tarplin method](http://www.luketarplin.com/blog/fixing-postfix-plesk-configuration-problem), but commenting out those lines in the `/etc/postfix/main.cf` have stopped working since the 10.4.4 update to PLESK for some reason.

I've seen other suggestions including adding MX records, modifying the `main.cf` in different ways.  I know very little about MTA's and even less about DNS settings.

Does anyone have any advice on a solution to making Postfix treat all email recipients the same and just send the email instead of reverting to local?

Below is from my maillog, I have it sending to 2 emails, 1 a gmail, one with the same address as a vhost.  As you can see, one gets sent, one does not.

```
Aug  2 05:52:27 server1 postfix/pickup[5242]: C2187750: uid=10013 from=<thermo-ta-ftp>
Aug  2 05:52:27 server1 postfix/cleanup[5498]: C2187750: message-id=
 <20120802095227.C2187750@server1.onlinehome-server.com>
Aug  2 05:52:27 server1 postfix/qmgr[32727]: C2187750: 
 from=<thermo-ta- ftp@server1.onlinehome-server.com>, size=1063, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Aug  2 05:52:27 server1 postfix-local[5503]: postfix-local: 
 from=thermo-ta-ftp@server1.onlinehome-server.com, to=info@company.com, 
 dirname=/var/qmail/mailnames
Aug  2 05:52:27 server1 postfix-local[5503]: cannot chdir to mailname dir info: No such
  file or directory
Aug  2 05:52:27 server1 postfix-local[5503]: Unknown user: info@company.com
Aug  2 05:52:27 server1 postfix/pipe[5501]: C2187750: to=<info@company.com>, 
 relay=plesk_virtual, delay=0.17, delays=0.11/0/0/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent 
 (delivered via plesk_virtual service)
Aug  2 05:52:28 server1 postfix/smtp[5502]: certificate verification failed for gmail-
 smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.225.26]:25: untrusted issuer /C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax
  Secure Certificate Authority
Aug  2 05:52:29 server1 postfix/smtp[5502]: C2187750: to=<regular.address@gmail.com>,
  relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.225.26]:25, delay=1.6, 
 delays=0.11/0.01/0.29/1.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1343901326 
 s4si23521367igw.27)
Aug  2 05:52:29 server1 postfix/qmgr[32727]: C2187750: removed
```

**UPDATE:  This is 100% a PLESK issue, and it applies to almost all versions of 10 and 11.  The QMail MTA also reverts to a local handler if the vhost domain matches the email recipient.**

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

> Aug  2 05:52:27 server1 postfix-local[5503]: postfix-local:
>   from=thermo-ta-ftp@server1.onlinehome-server.com, to=info@company.com,
>   dirname=/var/qmail/mailnames
>   Aug  2 05:52:27 server1 postfix-local[5503]: cannot chdir to mailname dir info: No such   file
>   or directory
>   Aug  2 05:52:27 server1 postfix-local[5503]: Unknown
>   user: info@company.com

The beguiling name of "postfix-local" notwithstanding, this is not a postfix component, but a plesk $something.

The fact that it accepts mail and then does not deliver it should tell you enough about the dependability of this software :)

Couple that with the fact that "dirname=/var/***qmail***/mailnames" does not look like a postfix-related item at all, and I doubt that there is anything in postfix causing this issue.

Comment: Hmmm, that makes more sense beings what this error didn't start occurring until PLESK updated, but I did "fix" it the first time by modifying the `main.cf` of Postfix.  I appreciate your insight.